# C# WPF CheckBox Command not Binded

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

View:

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
     <CheckBox x:Name="chk_Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
         Command="{Binding Chk_GridTop}"/>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
```

View Model:

```
public partial class ViewModel_AC: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ICommand _chkGridTop;

    public ICommand Chk_GridTop
    {
        get { return _chkGridTop ?? (_chkGridTop = new DelegateCommand(_chk_GridTop)); }
    }

    public void _chk_GridTop(object check)
    {
     //Empty
    }
}
```

DelegateCommand

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("execute can no null");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null)
    {

    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute.Invoke(parameter);
    }
}
```

There are other Commands bind with buttons which working well, but checkBox command is not working

I want to fire Chk_GridTop when checkBox is checked or unchecked

Is it something wrong what i use that?

Answer (score -1):

add CommandParameter

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <CheckBox x:Name="chk_Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
         Command="{Binding Chk_GridTop}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=IsChecked}"/>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
```